# Hamburger menu require 2 clicks to re-open. conflicting jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

In order to access the the mobile navigation menu a second time, I am required to click the hamburger icon TWICE.

site here http://shitnavbar.brodiedigital.io/

Steps to reproduce:

- Ensure browser is viewing mobile, or at least tablet width, so as the hamburger icon appears on the navbar only
- Scroll past 100vh to ensure the navbar is in field of view
- Click hamburger icon (menu will appear)
- click an navigation item, ie 'BIKES'
- Nav menu will collapse, you will be directed to the 'Bikes' section.
- Click hamburger icon (menu will NOT appear on click)
- Click hamburger icon (menu will now appear, and work as intended)

My code as follows:

```
  function initMenu()
  {
    if($('.hamburger').length && $('.menu').length)
    {
      var hamb = $('.hamburger');

      hamb.on('click', function()
      {
        if(!menuActive)
        {
          openMenu();
        }
        else
        {
          closeMenu();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  function openMenu()
  {
    menu.addClass('active');
    menuActive = true;
  }

  function closeMenu()
  {
    menu.removeClass('active');
    menuActive = false;
  }
```

and I also have the following logic for clicking and anchor in the mobile navbar

```
$('.menu_nav_list a').on('click', function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();                         
    $(this).closest('.menu').removeClass('active');  
});
```

I think that the second part of code needs to include the function 'closeMenu()'  - I have been trying to add that function to the second part of code, but it's not having any affect.

The first chunk of code is in a separate js file, the 2nd part is just plonked in the HTML file, below the link/ref to the seperate js file - so was hoping the function would be available to use.

Is there a way I can combine these 2, so that clicking on a '.menu_nav_list' anchor also triggers the function closeMenu()?

Comment: Given that you are controlling the state of the menu with the `active` class, the `menuActive` variable is rather unnecessary.  `menu.hasClass('active')` will give you that boolean without having to maintain a secondary stateful variable

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your click logic is only removing the class.  It's not changing the state variable.

```
$('.menu_nav_list a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.menu').removeClass('active');
    menuActive = false;
});
```

This is the very reason why having stateful variables that reflect a state in the DOM are a **bad idea**.  You have to maintain both.  Rather than maintaining **menuActive**, if you instead checked `menu.hasClass('active')` to get that boolean, you would save an extra variable, and you would never risk becoming out fo sync.

EDIT: Or like you stated towards the end, your click handler could reuse the `closeMenu()` method without repeating that logic.  Which would just look like:

```
$('.menu_nav_list a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    closeMenu();
});
```

Comment: frustratingly this didnt work. would you be a star and show me what the code would look like, using the closeMenu() function ? I'd really appreciate it

Comment: Then something is incorrect with the implementation.  I placed a debugger statement on your page where it checks to see if menuActive is false to open the menu, and in the case that you have to double click, it is indeed still true on the first click